Finding Smith normal form of a $\mathbb C[\lambda]$-matrix
Let $J_n(\lambda)$ denote the Jordan block of size $n$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e.
$$J_n(\lambda)=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & & \\
& \lambda & \ddots & \\
& & \ddots & 1\\
& & & \lambda
\end{pmatrix},$$
Then $J_n(\lambda)$ could be viewed as a matrix over the ring $\mathbb C[\lambda]$. What is the Smith normal form of $J_n^n(\lambda)=(J_n^n(\lambda))^n$?
For example, the matrix $J_3^3(\lambda)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^3 & 3\lambda^2 & 3\lambda\\
0 & \lambda^3 & 3\lambda^2\\
0 & 0 & \lambda^3
\end{pmatrix}$, and the Smith form is $\text {diag}\{\lambda, \lambda^3, \lambda^5\}$.
Some brute force calculations show that the Smith form of general $J_n^n(\lambda)$ is very likely to be $$\text {diag}\{\lambda, \lambda^3, \dots, \lambda^{2n-1}\}  (\ast)$$  Is there any way to prove it? Moreover, if possible, can we do the more general case $J_n^m(\lambda)$ where $m\ne n$? Thanks for any help in advance.
(Motivation: I ended up with this $\lambda$-matrix while trying to determine the Jordan form of $I_n\otimes J_n(0)+ J_n(0)\otimes I_n$. I have already shown in other approaches that the largest Jordan block of $I_n\otimes J_n(0)+ J_n(0)\otimes I_n$ has size $2n-1$ and it has exactly $n$ Jordan blocks (which matches with the conjecture $(\ast)$). But I can't prove that the explicit Jordan form is $\text{diag}\{J_1(0),J_3(0),\dots, J_{2n-1}(0)\}$. It would also be appreciated if any of u solve this more original problem:)
Edit: Jyrki's answer probably does the work, but as I don't have any knowledge of Lie algebra, I need a more elementary answer

The 'more-original' problem was once asked in Finding a Jordan normal form of a matrix that is almost Jordanform-like, but no satisfactory answers there

This is a very partial answer. I provide only a Lemma which would ( I believe) allow Jyrki Lahtonen to deal with his point (2) and so complete his solution.
We wish to prove that the North-East minors of $J_n(\lambda)^n$ are non-zero. As the $k\times k$ such minor is a multiple of $\lambda^{k^2}$ it suffices to show that the North-East minors of $J_n(1)^n$ are non-zero.
Recall that if $A^{(k)}$ denotes the matrix of $k\times k$ minors of $A$ then we have that $(AB)^{(k)}=A^{(k)}B^{(k)}$. So it will suffice to prove that for all $k=1,2,\dots,n$ the most North-East entry of $(J_n(1)^{(k)})^n$ is non-zero.
Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the basis of the underlying vector space, so that $J_n(1)e_i=e_i+e_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\dots,n-1$ and $J_n(1)e_n=e_n$.
The basis for $V^{(k)}=V\wedge\dots\wedge V$ ($k$-fold) consists of all $e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k}$ with $1\le i_1<\dots<i_k\le n$. The action of $J_n(1)^{(k)}$ is given by
$$
J_n(1)^{(k)}(e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k})=(e_{i_1}+e_{i_1+1})\wedge\dots\wedge (e_{i_k}+e_{i_k+1})
$$
where we use the convention that $e_{n+1}=0$.
Now expand this wedge product and note the following:
(a) the term $e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k}$ occurs with coefficient $1$;
(b) any term $e_{j_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{j_k}$ which appears has $j_1<\dots<j_k$, so that no term needs to be re-ordered;
(c) hence all the coefficients are non-negative integers;
(d) if $i_k<n$ the term $e_{j_1+1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{j_k+1}$ appears with coefficient $1$.
We can now show that the most North-Easterly entry of $(J_n(1)^{(k)})^n$ is indeed non-zero. Recall that the matrix $A:=J_n(1)^{(k)}$ has its rows and columns indexed by ordered $k$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$; if $I$ and $\hat{I}$ are such then let us write the matrix entry as $a_{I,\hat{I}}$.
In view of (c) all we need to provide is a set of $n$ ordered $k$ subsets $L_1=\{1,2,\dots, k\}, L_2,\dots, L_n=\{n-k+1,\dots,n\}$ such that the $a_{L_1,L_2}a_{L_2,L_3}\dots a_{L_{n-1},L_n}\ne 0$; that is that each $a_{L_s,L_{s+1}}\ne 0$.
We can do this by choosing the $L_s$ in this way:
(i) First choose $L_2:=\{2,\dots,k+1\},\dots, L_{n-k+1}:=\{n-k+1,\dots,n\}$. By (d) each of these $a_{L_s,L_{s+1}}\ne 0$.
(ii) Now choose the remaining $L_s= \{n-k+1,\dots,n\}$; by (a) these $a_{L_s,L_{s+1}}\ne 0$ too.

Summarizing an IMHO promising line of attack. Not a solution, as one step is missing, but I suspect this works.

Let $N$ be the strictly upper diagonal $n\times n$ matrix with $1$s immediately above the diagonal, and zeros elsewhere. So the powers of $N$ move the $1$s towards Northeast, and $N^n=0$. We have $J_n(\lambda)=\lambda I_n+N$, and hence by the binomial formula
$$
J_n(\lambda)^n=\lambda^nI_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom n k\lambda^{n-k}N^k.
$$
The suggested attack depends on the well known fact that the invariant factors $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n$ of an $m\times n$-matrix $A$ over a PID, $m\ge n$, are determined (up to a unit factor) by the formula telling that the product $d_1d_2\cdots d_k$
is equal to the gcd of the $k\times k$-minors of $A$. For all $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Look at the top right $k\times k$ minor of $J_n(\lambda)^n$. Show that all the terms in that determinant are scalar multiples of $\lambda^{k^2}$.
Show that the determinant in step 1 is a non-zero scalar multiple of $\lambda^{k^2}$. (Warning: I don't know how to prove this, yet.)
Show that all the other $k\times k$ minors of $J_n(\lambda)^n$ are divisible by $\lambda^{k^2}$.
Conclude that the gcd of all the minors with $k$ rows and columns is $\lambda^{k^2}$. Done.

In verifying steps 1 and 3 I used the fact that every permutation is a product of 2-cycles, and the observation that modifying a permutation by a 2-cycle won't change the degree of the relevant product of matrix entries. As I already commented, I don't know how the key missing step 2 goes, and therefore I won't vouch for the viability of this attack. Good luck!

Then all we need to do is proving that the top right $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix has a nonzero determinant

@Jyrki I cannot complete it, but for (2) I think one can perhaps make progress by using the fact that $((I+N)^{n})^{(k)}=((I+N)^{(k)})^{n}$, and then one just has to show that there is at least one path of length $n$ on a certain directed graph on the $k$-subsets of ${1,\dots, n}$ joining the final subset to itself.

A way of solving your underlying problem that I spotted comes from familiarity with representations of Lie algebras, $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ in particular. That's because there is an element (one of the ladder operators you may have seen on a course in quantum mechanics) $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ that acts on an $n$-dimensional irreducible representation, denoted $V(n-1)$ (algebraists use the highest weight as opposed to the dimension to parametrize such objects), as $J_n(0)$ with respect to a certain basis. Then $x$ acts on the tensor product $V(n-1)\otimes V(n-1)$ exactly via
$T:=I_n\otimes J_n(0)+J_n(0)\otimes I_n$. A key is that by a so called Clebsch-Gordon formula:
$$
V(n-1)\otimes V(n-1)\simeq V(2n-2)\oplus V(2n-4)\oplus\cdots\oplus V(2)\oplus V(0).
\qquad(*)
$$
Here $T$ respects the decomposition $(*)$,
and this leads to the claimed result as follows. Unfortunately I need to use the properties of the modules $V(m)$. What happens is that the submodules $V(2(n-k)),k=1,2,\ldots,n$, are the Jordan blocks of $T$ in $V(n-1)\otimes V(n-1)$. Furthermore, every space $V(m)$ has such a basis that the restriction of $T$ w.r.t. that basis is represented by the matrix $J_{m+1}(0)$.

In every module $V(m), m\ge0$, there is a 1-dimensional space (called the highest weight space) annihilated by $x$. In other words, the kernel of $T$ has dimension $n$ as there are $n$ summands on the right hand side of $(*)$.
Whenever $m>0$ the module has another basis vector (mapped to the highest weight space by $T$) that is not annihilated by $T$ but is annihilated by $T^2$. The rightmost summand on the r.h.s. of $(*)$ is now out of reckoning, and we see that the kernel of $T^2$ has dimension $n+(n-1)$.
Then it gets slightly more complicated, but, recursively, whenever $j\le m$, the space $V(m)$ has another vector annihilated by $T^{j+1}$ but not yet by $T^j$. In $(*)$ we always have $m\ge2$ save for the last summand, so the first $n-1$ summands contribute to the kernel of $T^3$ and therefore
$$\dim ker(T^3)=n+(n-1)+(n-1).$$
When we look at the kernel of $T^4$, the summand $V(2)$ no longer contributes (it is annihilated completely by $T^3$). Consequently $\dim ker(T^4)=(n-2)+\dim ker(T^3)$ as well as $\dim ker(T^5)=(n-2)+\dim ker(T^4)$.
From that point on the summands in the r.h.s. of $(*)$ drop out one-by-one, after every other iteration of $T$. The last man standing is the summand $V(2n-2)$ which will be annihilated in its entirety by $T^{2n-1}$.
As a reality check we see that the kernel of $T^{2n-1}$ has dimension
$$\sum_{j=1}^nj+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=n^2.$$


It may be possible to translate this into language that does not require the theory of Lie algebras and their representations. One way would be to use bivariate polynomials and partial differential operators, but I don't remember how the decomposition $(*)$ is written in that language. A possibility is to use eigenspaces of a Casimir operator, but I need more time to do that.
